# Как включить автоконфиг на виндоус 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, wifi

Я использовал netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface="Wi-Fi"чтобы стабилизировать пинг. На следующий день я не смог врубить интернет. Пытался использовать netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Wi-Fi", но консоль пишет «Беспроводной интерфейс в системе отсутствует.» Пробовал сбросить настройки сети, не помогло.

Comment: Удали вайфай из диспечера устройств (только галку "удалить драйвера" не трогай) и нажми "поиск новых устройств".

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой, в итоге методом тыка нашел решение:

В русскоязычной версии Windows Wi-Fi, видимо, называется "Беспроводная сеть".
Как можно видеть на скриншоте, в конце я достиг желаемого результата.

Мне помогла команда

> show

А точнее

> show interfaces

Которая и показала, что нет интерфейса "Wi-Fi", но есть интерфейс "Беспроводная сеть"

Итоговая строчка в командной строке:

> netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Беспроводная сеть"

[image: Команда show interfaces выводит список доступных интерфейсов]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Я все продублировал текстом. Картинка здесь лишь демонстрирует поведение командной строки в ответ на команды, указанные выше в решении

Comment: так вот то, что у вас на картинке, гораздо лучше было вставить текстом. почему — подробно описано по ссылке, которую я привёл выше.